# How to enable Ble Advertising using hci tool on android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

I have tried to use hci tool for enabling ble advertising on android.I could use hci tool on bluez stack which was used in android before bluedroid. But now, i failed to use it on latest versions of android. I have followed this question but of no help. Any help will be appreciated.

[Bluetooth HCI command for enabling BLE advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907675/bluetooth-hci-command-for-enabling-ble-advertising)

Answer (score 1):

on the latest Android, hci tool can't be used. What will work is the bdt(the bluedroid test tool).

Comment: ok. i explored that tool but i m doubtful that i will be able enable ble advertising using that tool.